# Get real URL of Facebook Story video

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, html5, safari

On the desktop when I watch a video posted to Facebook Days/Stories using Safari, I can right click the video and press "Copy video address" and I will get the real URL. But in Chrome, it gives me a `blob` URL.

"Inspect element" doesn't reveal the video's real URL, so how do I get it in Chrome, both with and without a plugin? Can it be done in Edge? Internet Explorer? If you suggest a plugin, it *must* be able to give me the video URL as opposed to just downloading the video.

If you can, tell me why Safari exposes the real URL while Chrome does not.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, Facebook does not have a single file for videos. They seem to store the video in 2 separate files, the video file and the audio file, both stored as MP4 files.

The two files are loaded in chunks (streamed). The URL used to load the chunk of MP4 file specifies the bytestart and byteend as parameters to tell the server which section of the video or audio file is being loaded.

Facebook glues the chunks together into the blob that you see when you inspect the video URL in the page's HTML code.

I found out this info by opening the developer tools in the chrome browser, and looking at the Network Tab while a video file was playing. put the text MP4 into the filter function, so only urls matching the text MP4 are displayed.

To get the complete video file and complete audio file, you would need to get the URLs for both MP4 files. Once you have 2 unique MP4 file URLs, alter  the bytestart parameter to 0 and the byteend parameter to something really large like 9999999 (im not sure what the max byte size you can use is, but you could experiment with it, if you are not getting the complete file, try making the byteend number larger.

Once you have both files you would need to combine them in a video editor to get a single video file with audio and video merged.

**Update** Having said all that, on the mobile version of the website, facebook does serve complete video/audio files, so if you get the URL for the Story from the desktop site, e.g https://www.facebook.com/stories/117935330119473
then change it to the mobile website version by replacing "www" with "m"
i.e https://m.facebook.com/stories/117935330119473

Then load the Story, if you look at the network tab this time, and filter the urls for mp4, you should see a url for a single combined video and audio file, that you can copy and paste into your browser, then once its loaded you should be able to save the file. Or alternatively simply inspect the HTML code of the page, and look for the `<video` tag, and copy the source URL from there for the full video file.

Answer (score 0):

Safari differs from Chrome in [Blob support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740767/download-blob-in-safari):

> Safari has a serious issue with blobs that are of the type application/octet-stream

So that is why they do not use blob URLs for video streams. In order to get the URL, use a packet sniffer such as the following:

- [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)
- [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/networkpacketcapture)
- [Win10Pcap](http://www.win10pcap.org/)
- [Wireless Diagnostics](http://osxdaily.com/2015/04/23/sniff-packet-capture-packet-trace-mac-os-x-wireless-diagnostics/)

Comment: What? No, no, no, no, no. Safari's capability is what I want. This should be viewed as a bug for Chrome. Why would they support blob URLs?

Comment: Is there anyway to get the URL in Chrome *without* using a packet sniffer? It's ridiculous that I would have to resort to that just to see an item's source URL.

Comment: @melab You can try opening the chrome://net-internals/#events URL in a tab to see if it shows up there.

Comment: check my answer below for some more details on how facebook serves video files